# change line delimiter of all existent files

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on a project with thousands of files.
The workspace was set to windows line delimiter when created.

However I need to change them to Unix.
I've found the setting:

```
New text file line delimiter
```

which works for new files. But not for the existent ones.

Is there a setting for resetting line delimiters for all existent files on a workspace?

Comment: `File > Convert Line Delimiters To > Unix`

Comment: @greg-449 this is what i'm using to convert current file but I want to convert all files

Comment: You can invoke the operation with multiple projects selected and it will give you a dialog where you can choose what to convert

Comment: @greg-449 that solves my issue, thank you very much! Post it as the question answer if you want so I can select it as the solution